# Javascript adding multiple css selectors using a function and classList

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to add multiple css selectors to an element using `classList` that's inside a function, but keep getting the below error. How do I do this right?

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'add' on 'DOMTokenList': 
The token provided ('padding fonts') contains HTML space characters, which are not valid in tokens.
```

https://jsfiddle.net/nordy/h84gadst/1/

```
function addStyle(element,styleName) {
    element.classList.add(styleName);
}

var targetElement = document.getElementById("parent-container");

var addStyleElement = document.getElementById("addStyle");

addStyleElement.onclick = function() {
    addStyle(targetElement,'padding fonts');
}
```

Comment: [Massive dupe](https://www.google.com/search?q=classlist+add+several+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: The issue is that you're adding more than one class. It does not work that way. To add multiple classes we do like so `div.classList.add("foo", "bar", "baz");` not `div.classList.add("foo bar baz");` as you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

The main problem is that classes cannot contain spaces, you can add multiple classes separated with comas like this:

```
element.classList.add('padding','fonts');
```

**EDIT:** If you want to send multiple classes in the same string, you can do this in the method:

```
function addStyle(element,styleName) {
    styleName.split(" ").forEach(class => element.classList.add(class));
}
```

Comment: So how do I call addStyle() when using multiple selectors?

Comment: @Norman you can do a .split(" ") in the method, and then doing a classList.add() for each one

Answer (score 1):

If you do it like this it should work, the space is the issue

```
addStyleElement.onclick = function() {
addStyle(targetElement,'padding');
addStyle(targetElement,'fonts');
```

}

Comment: I'm trying to do it together `addStyle(targetElement,'padding fonts')`

Comment: I understand but the space is generating the error

Comment: Edit your function definition like so:


function addStyle(element,styles) {
    element.classList.add(...styles);
}

We take the help of the spread operator.

Now you can call it like this:

addStyleElement.onclick = function() {
    addStyle(targetElement,['padding', 'fonts']);
}

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Solves the problem, but won't work for IE users.